# Principal differences between animals created on the fifth and the sixth days

Tags: animals, creation, genesis-bereishith

IIRC, the Jewish tradition divides between inanimated nature, plants, animal kingdom, and humans. I'm not aware of any principal differences within the animal kingdom. However, in the Creation narrative, some creatures are created on the 5th day ([Genesis.1.20](http://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.1.20-21?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)):

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים יִשְׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם שֶׁרֶץ נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה וְעוֹף יְעוֹפֵף עַל־הָאָרֶץ עַל־פְּנֵי רְקִיעַ הַשָּׁמָיִם׃ וַיִּבְרָא אֱלֹהִים אֶת־הַתַּנִּינִם הַגְּדֹלִים וְאֵת כׇּל־נֶפֶשׁ הַחַיָּה  הָרֹמֶשֶׂת אֲשֶׁר שָׁרְצוּ הַמַּיִם לְמִינֵהֶם וְאֵת כׇּל־עוֹף כָּנָף לְמִינֵהוּ...׃
> God said, “Let the waters bring forth swarms of living creatures and birds that fly above the earth across the expanse of the sky. God created the great sea monsters, and all the living creatures of every kind that creep, which the waters brought forth in swarms, and all the winged birds of every kind.

And some on the 6th:

> וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים תּוֹצֵא הָאָרֶץ נֶפֶשׁ חַיָּה לְמִינָהּ בְּהֵמָה וָרֶמֶשׂ וְחַיְתוֹ־אֶרֶץ לְמִינָהּ וַיְהִי־כֵן׃
> God said, “Let the earth bring forth every kind of living creature: cattle, creeping things, and wild beasts of every kind.” And it was so.

Rashi interprets "נפש חיה. שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ חַיּוּת:", but does he explicitly (לאפוקי) mean that those created on the day before lacked vitality?

From the ontological point, what is the principal difference between those two groups of the animal kingdom?

Comment: Could it not just be because they were a natural follow on i.e. the sky and the sea had been created so they went first followed by the rest of the animals on the next day?

Comment: Look at Sifsei Chachamim about the "נפש חיה. שֶׁיֵּשׁ בָּהּ חַיּוּת" point - https://www.sefaria.org/Siftei_Chakhamim%2C_Genesis.1.20.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Dov A keen observation (#1). Do we somehow differentiate between fish, fowls, and animals soul-wise? Because I don't know another division.

Comment: No idea I'm afraid